# CSS Newbie: CSS not rendering on Android but does render with Visual Studio Ripple Virtual Nexus (Galaxy)

Tags: android, css, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ripple

My CSS renders quite drastically from the Ripple Nexus(Galaxy) and my Samsung Galaxy. Note the buttons and UL elements. I didn't find where the CSS I was trying to use wasn't supported on Android and the header and footer seem to be recognizing the CSS.  Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

[image: Physical Phone]

[image: Ripple Virtual Phone]

**The HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link href="css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>GPS</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>My Cool GPS</h1>
        </div>



        <div class="container btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg btn-block text-uppercase panel panel-default panel-borderless">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="main.getPosition()">Current Position</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="main.watchPosition()">Watch Position</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="main.stopWatching()">Stop Watching</button>
        </div>



        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info text-uppercase">Increment: <span class="label label-primary h1" ng-bind="main.incrementer"></span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info text-uppercase">distance: <span class="label label-primary h1" ng-bind="main.distance"></span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info text-uppercase">latitude: <span class="label label-primary h1" ng-bind="main.latitude"></span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info text-uppercase">longitude: <span class="label label-primary h1" ng-bind="main.longitude"></span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info text-uppercase">accuracy: <span class="label label-primary h1" ng-bind="main.accuracy"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>




    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">My Cool GPS</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS:**

```css
form {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#title {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#summary {
    font-size: 35px;
}

#summary img {
    float: right;
}

#error-msg {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:  50%;
    font-weight: bold;    
}

.page-header{
    text-align:center;
}

.footer {
    text-align:center;
}

.panel-borderless {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> can you add https and try again?

Comment: Yeah, that was it, not sure how I missed that "https:" got deleted and why it was still working in Ripple but I added it back and it works great!  Thanks!

Comment: ty but correct answer not mine?

Comment: Your answer was as a comment so it didn't have a voting button.  Can you add as an answer?

Comment: I add answer ty

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstra‌​p.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

can you add https and try again?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't loading the bootstrap.min.css in one of them.

If its not loading on the phone then I'd suspect a whitelisting issue - try using `chrome://inspect/#devices` when the phone is connected to a PC running chrome- this should enable you to see what the issue is.

Another question to ask is whether you should just be including a static copy of the CSS rather than using a CDN